# Simplify this If statement so it doesn't duplicate code - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an If statement that runs within a 'for' loop to create markers for a Google map. Basically if a tick box is not ticked it runs the code all displays all markers, but if a checkbox is ticked then it checks for a 2nd parameter and only runs the code for the items that match this condition.

The code I have below works fine, but it means I have to use the same code in both parts of the if statement. Apart from building it into a function if there a better way of structuring the If statement to achieve this?

```
if(!FriendlyChecked){

    //Code here

} else if(FriendlyChecked && Friendly == "Yes"){

    //Same code here

}
```

Comment: Your else if condition is redundant. If `FriendlyChecked` is `true` (in which case it will go to the else if statement) then why are you checking if `FriendlyChecked` is `true` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( !FriendlyChecked || (FriendlyChecked && Friendly == "Yes") ) {

  // your code

}
```

`!FriendlyChecked || (FriendlyChecked && Friendly == "Yes")` will check for either `FriendlyChecked` is `false` (not checked)

**OR** `FriendlyChecked` is `true` an value of `Friendly` is `Yes`

Comment: Beat me to it by about 3 secs.

Answer (score 9):

If `FriendlyChecked` is false, the first condition is satisfied and the code will be executed.

Thus, if the second condition is reached, `FriendlyChecked` must be true, so you don't need to check it at all, you only need to check that `Friendly == "Yes"`.

```
if(!FriendlyChecked || Friendly == "Yes"){
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
 if((!FriendlyChecked) ||((FriendlyChecked)&&(Friendly == "Yes")){

 //Code here

}
```